# Finding sum of binomial series

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

[image]
Find the sum of this series.

I tried writing the general term of this term. I succeeded in it but the sum inside the bracket depends on r which makes more problem to get overall sum.  I know that this uses the concept of  binomial theorem and binomial coefficients but I am not able to break through it to get the desired concept to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First,
by the binomial theorem,
$\sum_{r=0}^n (-1)^r\binom{n}{r}x^r
=(1-x)^n
$.

Second,
the series on the right
has terms
$\dfrac{(2^j-1)^r}{2^{jr}}
=\left(\dfrac{2^j-1}{2^j}\right)^r
=(1-2^{-j})^r
$
for
$j = 1$ to $m$
so it is
$\sum_{j=1}^{m} (1-2^{-j})^r
$.

Note:
In my original answer,
I had 0 to m-1.
This is a correction.

Therefore
the sum is

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{r=0}^n (-1)^r\binom{n}{r}\sum_{j=1}^{m} (1-2^{-j})^r
&=\sum_{j=1}^{m}\sum_{r=0}^n (-1)^r\binom{n}{r} (1-2^{-j})^r\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{m}(1-(1-2^{-j}))^n\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{m}(2^{-j})^n\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{m}(2^{-n})^j\\
&=2^{-n}\dfrac{1-2^{-mn}}{1-2^{-n}}
\qquad\text{since }\sum_{j=1}^{m}x^j =x\dfrac{1-x^m}{1-x}
\text{ with } x=2^{-n}\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: I think there must be m over the summation sign instead of m-1 and j=1 in the subscript of the summation because the general term you wrote for that series gives 0 as the first term.

Comment: You are right. It should be 1 to m. I will correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\left(\sum_{r=0}^n\binom nr\left(\dfrac{1-2^m}{2^m}\right)^r\right)$$

Comment: I too have got this but I am stuck hereafter

Comment: You can apply the Binomial Theorem to the inner sum, right, Greninja?