# Find the value of $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}S_n$

Tags: calculus, limits, binomial-coefficients

> If $$S_n=\sum_{r=0}^{15}\binom{15}{r}\left\{\left(\frac{-1}{2}\right)^r+\left(\frac{-3}{4}\right)^r+\left(\frac{-7}{8}\right)^r+\cdots\textrm{upto n terms}\right\}$$
> Then find the value of $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}S_n$$

### Options

$1.$ $\frac{1}{2^{15}}$

$2.$ $\frac{1}{2^{15}+1}$

$3.$ $\frac{1}{2^{15}-1}$

$4.$ $\frac{-1}{2^{15}-1}$

---

At first, I was not able to figure out the pattern. But then I thought that the pattern could be like this $$\frac{-1}{2},\frac{-3}{4},\frac{-7}{8},\frac{-15}{16},\frac{-31}{32},\cdots$$
Subtracting powers of $2$ from numerators and adding the same powers of $2$ to denominators. But this is only my opinion.

---

I know that $$\sum_{r=0}^{15}\binom{15}{r}=2^{15}$$
I don't have a clue or two to solve this question. Should I make use of integrals$?$ If yes then how$?$

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2556594/finding-sum-of-binomial-series

Comment: Is the answer three?

Comment: Yes, the answer is option three.  The key is that for any real number $~x,~$ you have that $$\sum_{r=0}^{15} \binom{15}{r} ~x^r = (1 + x)^{15}.$$

Comment: You also need that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} y + y^2 + y^3 + \cdots + y^n = \frac{y}{1 - y} ~: ~-1 < y < 1.$$